# Application creates classroom invitation, but no email is being sent to student

Tags: google-api-client, google-classroom

After creating a classroom invitation the method classroom.create returns with the return status 200 but the user never receives email with the invitation message.

I have given the the client id associated with the service account that I am using, the scopes classroom.roster and mail.google.com, but nothing seems to work.
Am I missing something?

Thank you very much,
Andres
This is the fragment of code that creates the invitation:

```
//get authorization client

const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
    scopes
  });
//impersonate teacher account
  if (auth instanceof google.auth.JWT) {
    auth.subject = 'teacher_email@dom.edu';
    }


 const options = {    auth,     
                                requestBody: {
                                courseId: '19220887720',
                                role: 'STUDENT',
                                userId: 'student_email@dom.edu'
                                  }
  };
//send invitation
try {
    const invitation = await classroom.invitations.create(options);
    console.log('invitation was sent:', invitation);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('error: ' , err);
  }
```

Response: status 200.

The invitation is really created. Response includes an invitation id and  If you check on the ClassRoom home page->people you can see the correct student was invited.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-education/qtq10fWaKuI/8wrWGVeYxrIJ), students need to have the same settings on in their account, which they may not by default.  They should also choose to be a student first.

Also, notification e-mails of Google Classroom are sent from [classroom.google.com](https://classroom.google.com/) domain. See [Email notifications - Classroom Help](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6024971?hl=en&ref_topic=6024979) for further details.